# Clicar no link com vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, url, internet-explorer, click

Preciso clicar no objeto que possui o hyperlink para continuar a navegação na página.

O erro ocorre na linha: `ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).CLICK`.

```
Sub busca_desc()

Range("B3:g3").ClearContents 'limpo o range

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application") 'crio o objeto IE

ie.navigate "https://www.petronect.com.br/irj/go/km/docs/pccshrcontent/Site%20Content%20(Legacy)/Portal2018/pt/lista_licitacoes_publicadas_ft.html"  'Url do site
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE" ' aguardar a página carregar
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).Value = 7003383741# ' insiro o valor no campo para pesquisa
ie.document.getElementsByTagName ("button") 'aciono o botão pesquisar
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)

 
Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE" ' aguardar a página carregar
    DoEvents
Loop

'ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).CLICK ' Meu problema está aqui!! No resutado exibido preciso clicar no Objeto que possui o hyperlink.    

'ie.Quit

'Range("A3:g3").WrapText = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Caro Ícaro, sugiro a você formatar o código como bloco de código (basta adicionar quatro espaços antes de cada linha). Além disso, explicar qual é o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Caro Ícaro, seu problema, na verdade, começa bem antes.

A linha `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button") 'aciono o botão pesquisar` não faz absolutamente nada. Ela não chama nenhum método, nem instancia o botão numa variável, nem aciona o botão pesquisar -- inclusive porque `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")` retorna uma coleção de botões, e não um único botão. O botão "Peesquisar" é o 4º da coleção (índice 3).

Portanto, para clicar no botão pesquisar, você precisaria substituir a instrução acima por `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(3).Click 'aciono o botão pesquisar`

Além disso, indo para a parte que você já evidenciou no final do código, atualmente você está clicando na célula de tabela HTML que contém o link (`TD`). Isso realmente não produz resultado algum. Você quer, isso sim, clicar no link (`A`) que está dentro da célula.

**EDIÇÃO:** Inseri a parte da requisição, que você pediu nos comentários.

Portanto, seu código final ficaria assim:

```
Sub busca_desc()
    
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim tbody As HTMLTableSection
    Dim req As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim respostaJson As String, numOportunidade As String
    Dim i As Variant
    
    
    Range("B3:G3").ClearContents 'limpo o range
    numOportunidade = "7003383741" ' Na verdade, toda essa função estará dentro de uma iteração das células com os números de oportunidade que você quer consultar. Aqui, coloquei um valor fixo, mas você provavelmente apontara para o calor contido na célula atual da iteração
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer 'crio o objeto IE
    ie.navigate "https://www.petronect.com.br/irj/go/km/docs/pccshrcontent/Site%20Content%20(Legacy)/Portal2018/pt/lista_licitacoes_publicadas_ft.html"  'Url do site
    ie.Visible = True
    
    Do While ie.Busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE" ' aguardar a página carregar
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).Value = numOportunidade ' insiro o valor no campo para pesquisa
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(3).Click 'aciono o botão pesquisar
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
     
    Do While ie.Busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE" ' aguardar a página carregar
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set tbody = ie.document.getElementById("result")
    ' Aqui provavelmente você vai querer colocar uma estrutura de loop, algo como:
    For Each i In tbody.getElementsByTagName("a")
        req.Open "GET", "https://www.petronect.com.br/sap/opu/odata/SAP/YPCON_GET_HEADER_INFO_SRV/headerInfoSet('" & numOportunidade & "')?$format=json"
        req.send corpoReq
        respostaJson = req.responseText
        respostaJson = Replace(respostaJson, "\""", """") ' As aspas externas são, no VB, o que delimita uma string. As aspas duplicadas dentro da string são a forma de o VB entender que não se trata da aspa-fim-da-string, e sim de uma aspa dentro do texto da string. Portanto, o que estamos fazendo aí é substituir '\"' por '"'.
        ' Nesse momento, respostaJson conterá um texto bem longo, e a parte dele que importa para você é algo como:
        '"START_DATE":"2020-11-30","START_TIME":"10:00:00","QUOT_DEAD":"2021-02-19","QUOT_DEAD_TIME":"14:00:00","CREATED_AT_DATE":"2020-11-27","CREATED_AT_TIME":"17:19:50","TZONE":"Brasil - Distrito Federal","CURRENCY":"BRL","YPCON_MODALITY":"101","YPCON_MODALITY_NAME":"Licitação, Lei 13.303, Art. 28, CAPUT","PUBL_DOU_DATE":"2020-11-30","DISPUTE_MODE":"02","YPCON_OBJ_CONT_DESC":"Serviço de conceituação, planejamento, criação, manutenção de ambientes digitais que compõem a presença digital da PETROBRAS."
        ' Prontinho! Agora você vai parsear esse texto, buscando as variáveis que te interessarem.
    Next i

    'ie.Quit
    
    'Range("A3:g3").WrapText = False
    
End Sub
```

P.S.: Para habilitar as classes `InternetExplorer`, `HTMLTableSection` e outras, você precisa ir em Ferramentas -> Referências e selecionar a opção Microsoft HTML Object Library.

**EDIÇÃO:** Para habilitar a classe XMLHTTP60, você vai precisar fazer mais uma referência, dessa vez a "Microsoft XML, v. #.0" (a minha é 6.0).

Comment: Cesar, sou novo em programação. Conseguiria ajudar ainda mais? Obrigado
Veja minha lógica:
1º abrir a URL; 
2º pegar o ID que estará na minha planilha (Célula "A2" por exemplo); 
3º irá alimentar o ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3); 
4º acionará o botão pesquisar (ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(3).Click);
5º clicará no tbody.getElementsByTagName("a");
6º ao carregar a "nova" página irá alimentar  a planilha com o valor do id="object_descr_ctr";
7º após alimentar a planilha do respectivo ID da célula "A2", fará todo o processo novamente do próximo ID célula "A3".

Comment: Ok, a lógica me parece correta (lembrando que pode acontecer de um ID não retornar nenhum valor ou retornar mais de um valor). Você está com dificuldade de implementar algum desses passos?

Comment: É pouco provável que o ID não retorne valor, mas, bastaria um tratamento de erro e continuar o "Loop"?
Minha dificuldade agora está em capturar os valores da "nova" página após "click" e alimentar a planilha referente ao ID (Célula "A2" por exemplo); 
Pegando estes valores e alimentando a planilha, implementar o "Loop" até o último valor da coluna "A".

Comment: Naquela página que abre, quais são os dados que você quer pegar?

Comment: Se você tentar clicar no link da oportunidade que você filtrou, ele vai abrir uma página nova na mesma janela -- o que é um problema, pois depois, quando a gente voltar à página que contém os resultados, os objetos que estarão sendo iterados não estarão mais na memória.

Comment: A solução mais simples seria abrir em outra aba, mas não funciona, porque os links das oportunidades não apontam para uma URL. Eles fazem uma requisição assíncrona e retornam um JSON.

Comment: A segunda solução mais simples creio que seja fazer uma requisição HTML. Consegui fazer sem problemas e receber de volta o arquivo JSON com as informações. O problema aqui é que a empresa talvez tenha uma limitação da quantidade de requisições, ou algo assim, mas vale à pena testar. Diga quais informações você quer, e a gente conversa sobre isso.

Comment: Preciso de: Nome, Descrição do Objeto de Contratação, Data de Início e Data Fim:

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta, vê se funciona para você.

Comment: Em que variável está armazenando os valores?
Alimentei uma célula da plan com a "respostaJson", mas, não vem os valores que preciso.
Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Você pode postar nesse comentário uma resposta dessas?

Comment: Oi César, não entendi!

Comment: Você pode rodar um teste e colocar aqui o texto que retornou em um respostaJson desses?

Comment: Apliquei o seguinte comando: Cells(3, 5)  = respostaJson
O resultado foi:
{"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"WWW.PETRONECT.COM.BR:443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/…"},"Data":"","ObjectId":""}}

Comment: César, conseguiu identificar?
Obrigado desde já.